# how to pass the model of my current view to a controllers post action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, null

im trying to pass model via parameter with html.beginform to an action but it dont work, debuging the model appears null, dont understand why,
my code>

view

```
@model IEnumerable<GestorBd.Models.Receptor>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Receptores</h2>
<br />
Mostrando @Model.Count() elemento(s).
<br />
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm("ConvertThisPageToPdf", "Receptors", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { parame = Model }))
{
    
    <input type="submit" value="Convert
                        This Page To PDF" />


}
```

my controller  action

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ConvertThisPageToPdf(IEnumerable<Receptor> parame)
        {
            // get the HTML code of this view
            string htmlToConvert = RenderViewAsString("Index", parame);

            // the base URL to resolve relative images and css
            String thisPageUrl = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
/// and go on

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code create html tag (form) you can write input with name attr like this

```
<input type="text" name="your-name" id="your-name" />
```

into form scop

Comment: thanks for the answer, but with your code de object model is passing to the controller empty, i wanna the model with all the data cointained when the view was render

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. Firstly, I believe you are trying to send a complex model to a POST method via the query string rather than within the request body. To pass parameters via the query string you would need to add them via the `RouteValueDictionary` rather than the HTML attributes object. The HTML attributes object is used to add attributes, such as an `id`, to the actual form element.

However, I believe you would be much better passing the object in the request body. To do this you would need to add form HTML elements, for each receptor object, to pass the model properties to the server. For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConvertThisPageToPdf", "Receptors", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { id = "receptorsForm" }))
{
    <!-- Add the properties of your receptor objects -->
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        var receptor = Model.ElementAt(i);

        <!-- Note the index @i denotes that you are sending an array of items -->
        <input type="hidden" name="receptors[@i].Id" value="@receptor.Id" />
        <input type="hidden" name="receptors[@i].Name" value="@receptor.Name" />
        <input type="hidden" name="receptors[@i].Value" value="@receptor.Value" />
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Convert This Page To PDF" />
}
```

Assuming a C# model of:

```cs
public class Receptor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Note that the form element name must match the controller action parameter name for the correct model binding to happen. To correct this you would need to change the method signature to accept an enumerable of receptors:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConvertThisPageToPdf(IEnumerable<Receptor> receptors)
{
    //...
}
```

I've not tested this code but hopefully it should get you pretty close to what you need.

Comment: this works, the model is passed to the controller , and isnt empty cause i fill it in the beginform method, thanks,

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help. Could you mark as the answer if it solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a hidden input. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="receptors" value="@Model" />
```

this input will not be visible to your users but it will send to the controller action.
you can get the input value like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConvertThisPageToPdf(IEnumerable<Receptor> receptors)
{
    //...
}
```

or you can get the value using HttpContext.Request.Form:

```
var receptors = HttpContext.Request.Form["receptors"];
```

but there is one more thing, why you are using BeginForm since you can use the html form tag and asp.net tag helpers, if you want to use the BrginForm for some reasons you can add a hidden input like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m)
```

make sure that the arguments (action name and controller name) you'r passing to the BeginForm is correct.

Comment: using the hidden field to pass the model to the controller, the model pass empty,, i want the model with all the data that it has in the view.

Answer (score 0):

It might be old question but the way I solved is by serializing the model to json and send via ajax.

```
//Serialize Model to Json
'@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))'

//Post to Controller Action
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ConvertThisPageToPdf", "Receptors")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: '@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))',
    traditional: true,
    success: function (result) {
        
    }
});
```